# Ubuntu 22.04 and Gazebo Classic not working

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 to the 22.04 version. I installed ROS2 Humble (`sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop-full`) and I wanted to use Gazebo Classic with Nav2 simulations, but I cannot use it - my packages have unmet dependencies, that I couldn't fix.
Please hint me what I should do now.

My terminal logs:

- When I tried normal `sudo apt install gazebo`:

> ```
> ljaniec@ljaniec-PC:~$ gazebo
> > 
> >     Command 'gazebo' not found, but can be installed with:
> > 
> >     sudo apt install gazebo
> > 
> >     ljaniec@ljaniec-PC:~$ sudo apt install gazebo
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree... Done
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>
> or been moved out of Incoming.
>
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
>  gazebo : Depends: libgazebo11 (= 11.10.2+dfsg-1) but 11.12.0-1~focal is to be installed
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

- When I tried `sudo apt install ros-humble-gazebo-ros-pkgs`:

> ```
> ljaniec@ljaniec-PC:~$ sudo apt install ros-humble-gazebo-ros-pkgs 
> > 
> >     Reading package lists... Done
> > 
> >     Building dependency tree... Done
> > 
> >     Reading state information... Done
> > 
> >     Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> > 
> >     requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> > 
> >     distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> > 
> >     or been moved out of Incoming.
> > 
> >     The following information may help to resolve the situation:
> >     
> >     The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> >     
> >      gazebo : Depends: libgazebo11 (= 11.10.2+dfsg-1) but 11.12.0-1~focal is to be installed
> >     
> >      gz-tools2 : Conflicts: gazebo (>= 11.0.0) but 11.10.2+dfsg-1 is to be installed
> >     
> >      libgazebo-dev : Depends: libgazebo11 (= 11.10.2+dfsg-1) but 11.12.0-1~focal is to be installed
> >     
> >     E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
> >     
> >     ljaniec@ljaniec-PC:~$ sudo apt install libgazebo11
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree... Done
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> libgazebo11 is already the newest version (11.12.0-1~focal).
>
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> ```

Best
Łukasz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28553/ubuntu-22.04-and-gazebo-classic-not-working/) by [ljaniec](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/62948/ljaniec/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This problem was resolved, description: https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/issues/3277

```
# Check what is going to be removed 

dpkg -l | grep '^ii.*\(libignition\|sdformat\|gazebo\).*~focal'

# Remove everything 
while [[ -n $(dpkg -l | grep '^ii.*\(libignition\|sdformat\|gazebo\).*~focal' | awk '{ print $2 };') ]]; do sudo dpkg -r $(dpkg -l | grep '^ii.*\(libignition\|sdformat\|gazebo\).*~focal' | awk '{ print $2 }';); done

# Install new Gazebo on Jammy (or just install the humble desktop full) 

sudo apt install libgazebo-dev
```

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/62948/ljaniec/) with karma: 1 on 2022-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lfernandez](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/112227/lfernandez/) on 2022-11-17**:
Thanks @jlaniec but I'm not using focal repos but jammy. I haven't updated Ubuntu. It's a clean installation on Ubuntu 22.04.